# Ubuntu 17.10 crashed. How can I recover the lost files?

Tags: data-recovery, crash

I had trouble installing virtualbox for ubuntu 17.10. To run it properly I needed to configure dpkg and when I restarted the system it showed some lines of code like "failed to load resource and the platform".
I know how to install ubuntu again, because the first time I did with an USB and this time I'll do the same, but the problem is: How can I recover my files?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options here:

1. Boot from your installation USB drive, select advanced options, go into recovery mode, mount your file systems and copy your data off--perhaps to a different USB drive
2. Boot from your installation USB, reinstall the OS, but keep the filesystem intact during install

The following post should also prove to be helpful:

[How to Fix an Ubuntu System When it Won't Boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/)!